# What does this mean - Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to implement following kind of code

```
ValsProcessor {
    def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ) : Unit = { ....}
}

ValsProcessor2{
   def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ) : Unit = { ....}
}


val myFuncs2 : Map[String, () => Unit]=
      Map(
        "benchmark_model_vals" -> (() => new ValsProcessor().process), //Error
        "benchmark_model_vals2" -> (() => ValsProcessor2().process)
      )
'
```

Below error I am getting

> missing argument list for method process in class BenchmarkModelValsProcessor
> Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing process _ or process(*,*) instead of process.

What am I doing wrong here ? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `myFunc2` should have type `Map[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession) => Unit]`?

So try that:

```
val myFuncs2 : Map[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession) => Unit]=
  Map(
    "benchmark_model_vals" -> new ValsProcessor().process,
    "benchmark_model_vals2" -> ValsProcessor2().process
  )
```

Comment: sir tried but  getting different error object ValsProcessor is not a member of package com.snp.processors Note: class ValsProcessor exists, but it has no companion object.

Comment: why do I need a companion object here ? that only difference is ValsProcessor classes are placed in another package ie. com.snp.processors

Comment: Could you @user3252097 share all file?

Comment: trait Processor00 {
  def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ): Unit 
}
class BMValsProcessor extends Processor  {
   def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ) : Unit ={
     println("in BMValsProcessor")///actual business logic
   }
}
class BMValsProcessor2 extends Processor  {
   def process(oraOptionDfConfig: DataFrameReader, sparkSession: SparkSession ) : Unit ={
     println("in BMValsProcessor2")///actual business logic
   }
}

Comment: object ValProcessor {
   def main( args : Array[String]):Unit ={
     
     val df : DataFrameReader = null; // initialization of DataFrameReader
     val spark: SparkSession = null; // initialization of SparkSession
     
      val procs :Map[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession) => Unit] = getAllDefinedProcessors();
     
       procs.values.foreach(
                proc => proc(df,spark) 
        )
   }

Comment: def getAllDefinedProcessors(): Map[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession) => Unit] = {
     val myFuncs2 : Map[String, () => Unit]=
      Map(
        "bm_vals" -> (() =>  BMValsProcessor().process), //Error
        "bm_vals2" -> (() => BMValsProcessor2().process) //Error
      )
      myFuncs2;
   }
  
}

Comment: Just copy able 3 blocks in a scala object i.e. ValProcessor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53007811/how-to-fix-this-error-not-found-value-bmvalsprocessor

Comment: @user3252097 look into https://gist.github.com/AndriiStefaniv/902938c71440c3f25769528e5c730d4f

Comment: sir any clue about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042545/getting-sometimes-nullpointerexception-while-saving-into-cassandra  ..... sometimes it saves well but some times fails